# CMake with IBMs mpixlf2008

Tags: cmake, fortran, mpi

I am trying to compile a Fortran program using CMake on an IBM BlueGene machine. This is my source:

```
 > tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── test1.f90
```

where test1.f90 simply is:

```
program main
    use mpi
    integer   :: me, ierr

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, me, ierr)
    write (*,"(I4,A)") me, ": hello"
    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

I would like to create a ***static*** executable. Therefore I created this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.5)
project(STB)

file(GLOB_RECURSE sources  src/*.f90)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
add_executable(test.x ${sources})

enable_language(Fortran)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID "IBM")

if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "IBM")
    MESSAGE(STATUS "IBM")
    set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER mpixlf2008)
    set(dialect "-O2 -qarch=qp -qtune=qp -ufmt_littleendian={23}")
    set(debug "-C")
endif()


set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${bounds}")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${dialect}")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
MESSAGE( STATUS "cmake_module_path:    " ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
```

this results in:

```
make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/work/jias12/jias1217/test -B/work/jias12/jias1217/test --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /work/jias12/jias1217/test/CMakeFiles /work/jias12/jias1217/test/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
make -f CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
cd /work/jias12/jias1217/test && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /work/jias12/jias1217/test /work/jias12/jias1217/test /work/jias12/jias1217/test /work/jias12/jias1217/test /work/jias12/jias1217/test/CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
make -f CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/requires
make[2]: Entering directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/requires'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
make -f CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /work/jias12/jias1217/test/CMakeFiles 1
[100%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/src/test1.o
mpixlf2008   -O2 -qarch=qp -qtune=qp -ufmt_littleendian={23}   -c /work/jias12/jias1217/test/src/test1.f90 -o CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/src/test1.o
** main   === End of Compilation 1 ===
1501-510  Compilation successful for file test1.f90.
Linking Fortran executable test.x
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
mpixlf2008   -static  -O2 -qarch=qp -qtune=qp -ufmt_littleendian={23} CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/src/test1.o  -o test.x -rdynamic 
/opt/ibmcmp/xlf/bg/14.1/bin/.orig/bgxlf2008: 1501-210 (S) command option ynamic contains an incorrect subargument
make[2]: *** [test.x] Error 40
make[2]: Leaving directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/test'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I rerun the last argument without the -rdynamic

```
mpixlf2008   -static  -O2 -qarch=qp -qtune=qp -ufmt_littleendian={23} CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/src/test1.o  -o test.x
```

I get the error:

```
/bgsys/drivers/ppcfloor/gnu-linux/powerpc64-bgq-linux/bin/ld: -f may not be used without -shared
```

How can I compile my program using statically using CMake? If I simply run:

```
mpixlf2008 -c src/test1.f90
mpixlf2008 test1.o -o bla.x
```

The compilation works fine and the size(45M) suggest, that it's compiled statically.

**Edit:**

If I remove the little endian flag:

```
set(dialect "-O2 -qarch=qp -qtune=qp")
```

I can run the cmake created makefile and  then manually remove the -rdynamic

`mpixlf2008   -static  -O2 -qarch=qp -qtune=qp  CMakeFiles/test.x.dir/src/test1.o  -o test.x`

Which then successfully compiles. How can I remove the -rdynamic from the CMake Makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_Fortran_FLAGS)
```

allows me to remove the '-rdynamic'. This might be a bit manual, but for older CMake versions it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding -qstaticlink to your link line instead of adding -static / -rdynamic directly.  When you use the mpixlf2008 command, the compiler inserts its own -static / -rdynamic options to link in its own libraries, so the options you added are probably interfering with the ones the compiler is using.  The -qstaticlink option tells the compiler you want a completely static binary.  The option also has suboptions that would allow you to only statically link the gcc libraries.

Also, the specific error you're getting is because you specified "-rdynamic".  XLF doesn't know this option, so it assumes it's a grouping of smaller options.  So it parses it as: "-r -d -ynamic".  -r is for creating a nonexecutable output file, -d is for saving preprocessed output, -y is for specifying compile-time rounding mode.  The -y option takes a suboption for the rounding mode, e.g. -yn for nearest.  The error you're getting is that namic is not a known suboption of -y.  To pass -rdynamic to the linker, put -Wl, before it.  i.e. "-Wl,-rdynamic".